# Ionic 3 Infinite Scroll End When No More Data Is Found

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I am using json to data and what I want to do is I need to end infinite scroll once no more data is available.
How can I implement this.
Here is the code -

```
    loadData(currentCount) {
    this.http.get('http://www.exapmle.com/feed.php?page=' + this.currentCount).map(res => res.json()).subscribe(data => {
        this.posts1 = data;
        let i = 0;
        for (let v in this.posts1) {
            if (i < 4) {
                this.slidesdata.push(this.posts1[v]);
            } else {
                this.posts.push(this.posts1[v]);
            }
            i++;
        }
    });
}

    doInfinite(infiniteScroll: any) {
    this.currentCount = this.currentCount + 1;
    this.http.get('http://www.exapmle.com/feed.php?page=' + this.currentCount).map(res => res.json()).subscribe(data => {
        this.newposts1 = data;
        this.newposts = this.newposts1;
        for (let i in this.newposts) {
            this.posts.push(this.newposts[i]);
        }
        infiniteScroll.complete();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `*ngIf`.

**HTML:**

```
     <ion-infinite-scroll (ionInfinite)="doInfinite($event)">
            <ion-infinite-scroll-content loadingText="Loading your leads..." *ngIf="pagingEnabled"></ion-infinite-scroll-content>
        </ion-infinite-scroll> 
<div *ngIf="!pagingEnabled"> No more data is available.</div>
```

**TS**

```
public pagingEnabled: boolean = true;

 doInfinite(infiniteScroll: any) {
      this.currentCount = this.currentCount + 1;
      this.http.get('http://www.exapmle.com/feed.php?page=' + this.currentCount).map(res => res.json()).subscribe(data => {
          this.newposts1 = data;
          this.newposts = this.newposts1;  
          if (this.newposts.length) {
              for (let i in this.newposts) {
                  this.posts.push(this.newposts[i]);
              }
          } else {
              this.pagingEnabled = false;
          }

          infiniteScroll.complete();
      });
  }
```

Comment: If I merge those lines, the data from page 2 doesn't loads, and if I dont merge them, I get same error I got before - Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

Comment: Yes, it's working, but once there are no more pages left to load data, I get this error.

Comment: I assume at last call, you `API` returns an empty array

Comment: I am using pagination in API to call 10 rows at once and using infinite scroll to load more rows.But infinite scroll doesn't knows that there are no more pages left. So how can I use it to stop calling API once no more pages are there?

Comment: This answer is about this only. Forget about merge ignore that comment. put put other things in your code. updated ans try this

Comment: Still the same error. Is there any other way to load data without pagination?

Comment: That is not related to `infinitescroll`. The ans is to solve `end infinite scroll once no more data is available.`